# Discord.js Guild Member Add

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a bot to detect when a user joined. The code below does not work when my test account joins. Does it only work when it's the first time a user joins. If so, how can I make it work everytime.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
        // Send the message to a designated channel on a server:
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'general-chat');
        // Do nothing if the channel wasn't found on this server
        if (!channel) return;
        // Send the message, mentioning the member
        channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}`);
      });
```

Comment: Have you enabled the required intents? https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#symptoms-in-version-12

Comment: I have those enabled.

Comment: Have you debugged? Try logging inside the event to ensure it's emitting

Comment: Yes. I have checked and I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to enable Presence Intent on your bot settings on the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), which makes it able to detect new members.[Here's an screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CySGk.png).